# How to predict unseen data from trained multi-label text classification model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, bert-language-model, multilabel-classification

First I want to say I am completely new to machine learning and still learning how these things work. I am working on categorizing reviews into multiple labels and built a multi-label text classifier by referring to this [code](https://github.com/Moradnejad/Bert-Based-Tag-Recommendation/blob/main/tag-recommendation.ipynb).

The model is trained to categorize reviews into 9 labels and the model predicts the value for each label individually. Up to now how I trained the model and how I tested the model is as follows. I didn't include the text processing part otherwise it will be a lengthy code.

This is the model and it's the same one used [here](https://github.com/Moradnejad/Bert-Based-Tag-Recommendation/blob/main/tag-recommendation.ipynb)

```
#bert text model
class TEXT_MODEL(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self,
             vocabulary_size,
             embedding_dimensions=128,
             cnn_filters=50,
             dnn_units=512,
             model_output_classes=2,
             dropout_rate=0.1,
             training=False,
             name="text_model"):
    super(TEXT_MODEL, self).__init__(name=name)
    
    self.embedding = layers.Embedding(vocabulary_size,
                                      embedding_dimensions)
    self.cnn_layer1 = layers.Conv1D(filters=cnn_filters,
                                    kernel_size=2,
                                    padding="valid",
                                    activation="relu")
    self.cnn_layer2 = layers.Conv1D(filters=cnn_filters,
                                    kernel_size=3,
                                    padding="valid",
                                    activation="relu")
    self.cnn_layer3 = layers.Conv1D(filters=cnn_filters,
                                    kernel_size=4,
                                    padding="valid",
                                    activation="relu")          

    self.pool = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()
    
    self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(units=dnn_units, activation="relu")
    self.dropout = layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)
    if model_output_classes == 2:
        self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=1,
                                       activation="sigmoid")
    else:
        self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=model_output_classes,
                                       activation="softmax")

def call(self, inputs, training):
    l = self.embedding(inputs)
    l_1 = self.cnn_layer1(l) 
    l_1 = self.pool(l_1) 
    l_2 = self.cnn_layer2(l) 
    l_2 = self.pool(l_2)
    l_3 = self.cnn_layer3(l)
    l_3 = self.pool(l_3) 
    
    concatenated = tf.concat([l_1, l_2, l_3], axis=-1) # (batch_size, 3 * cnn_filters)
    concatenated = self.dense_1(concatenated)
    concatenated = self.dropout(concatenated, training)
    model_output = self.last_dense(concatenated)
    
    return model_output
```

This how I pass my tokenized reviews into the model and train it and finally tested it

```
    whole_predictions = []
    whole_real_predictions = []
    whole_threshold_predictions = []
    
    one=0
    #predict for each label individualy

for i in range(len(y_train[0])):
    print("\n" + str(i)+"\'th label prediction started")
    count_zero=0
    count_one=0
    new_label=[]
    new_tokenized_data_train=[]
    label = column(y_train,i)
    count_one=sum(label)
    print("count_one",count_one)
    
    for k in range(len(label)):
        if count_zero< count_one and label[k]==0:
            new_label.append(0)
            new_tokenized_data_train.append(X_train[k])
            count_zero=count_zero+1
        if label[k]==1:
            new_label.append(1)
            new_tokenized_data_train.append(X_train[k])

            
    print("count_zero",count_zero) 
    print()  
    data_with_len = [[value,new_label[j],len(value)]
                     for j,value in enumerate(new_tokenized_data_train)]


    data_with_len.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
    sorted_data_labels = [(data_lab[0], data_lab[1]) for data_lab in data_with_len]
    processed_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: sorted_data_labels, output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32))
    BATCH_SIZE = 32
    batched_dataset = processed_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=((None, ), ()))
    TOTAL_BATCHES = math.ceil(len(sorted_data_labels) / BATCH_SIZE)
    TEST_BATCHES = TOTAL_BATCHES // TOTAL_BATCHES
    batched_dataset.shuffle(TOTAL_BATCHES)
    test_data = batched_dataset.take(TEST_BATCHES)
    train_data = batched_dataset.skip(TEST_BATCHES)
    
   
    VOCAB_LENGTH = len(tokenizer.vocab)
    EMB_DIM = 260
    CNN_FILTERS = 50
    DNN_UNITS = 256
    OUTPUT_CLASSES = 2

    DROPOUT_RATE = 0.2

    NB_EPOCHS = 6

    text_model = TEXT_MODEL(vocabulary_size=VOCAB_LENGTH,
                        embedding_dimensions=EMB_DIM,
                        cnn_filters=CNN_FILTERS,
                        dnn_units=DNN_UNITS,
                        model_output_classes=OUTPUT_CLASSES,
                        dropout_rate=DROPOUT_RATE)

    if OUTPUT_CLASSES == 2:
        text_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                           optimizer="adam",
                           metrics=["acc"])
    else:
        text_model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                           optimizer="adam",
                           metrics=["sparse_categorical_acc"])

    text_model.fit(train_data, epochs=NB_EPOCHS)

    self_label_predictions = []
    self_threshold_predictions = []
    self_label_real_values = []
    print("Predicting " + str(i) + "th label...")
    
    for e,item in enumerate(X_test):
        if e%2==0:
            progress(e,len(X_test))
        res = text_model.predict([item])
        self_label_real_values.append(res[0][0])
      
        if res[0][0] > 0.93:
            self_threshold_predictions.append(res[0][0])
        else :
            self_threshold_predictions.append(0.0)

    whole_threshold_predictions.append(self_threshold_predictions)
    whole_real_predictions.append(self_label_real_values)

    
whole_threshold_predictions = list(map(list, zip(*whole_threshold_predictions)))
whole_real_predictions = list(map(list, zip(*whole_real_predictions)))
```

Now I need to use this `Text_model` to predict unseen data. So I studied similar cases and they have mentioned that I need to save and load the model and have to pass the data in a similar way when I train the model.
For now, I tried to go with the same model which is Text_model and the code is as follows.

```
   user=pd.read_csv("Noodlesam.csv")
    user=user.dropna()
    user['Trimmed text'] = user['Trimmed text'].astype(str).apply(text_cleaner)
    input=user['Trimmed text'].tolist()

    def tokenized_input(data):
        return tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer.tokenize(data))

    tokenized_input = [tokenized_input(data) for data in input]
    print(len(tokenized_input))

    new_whole_threshold_predictions=[]
    new_whole_real_predictions=[]
    new_self_threshold_predictions = []
    new_self_label_real_values = []

      for q,item1 in enumerate(tokenized_input):
              if q%2==0:            
                  progress(q,len(tokenized_input))
              res = text_model.predict([item1])
              new_self_label_real_values.append(res[0][0])
            
              if res[0][0] > 0.93:
                  new_self_threshold_predictions.append(1.0)
              else :
                  new_self_threshold_predictions.append(0.0)

      new_whole_threshold_predictions.append(new_self_threshold_predictions)
      new_whole_real_predictions.append(new_self_label_real_values)

  new_whole_threshold_predictions = list(map(list, zip(*new_whole_threshold_predictions)))
  new_whole_real_predictions = list(map(list, zip(*new_whole_real_predictions)))
```

But this gives me the output for only one label out of 9 labels. I quite understand in the previous code, train data has fit on the model inside `for k in range(len(label)):`loop that means 9 times. From this point, I don't understand how this model works and I need to know how I can use this model for unseen data.

I think this explains my issue and any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly. You train the model by setting the output of the model with `OUTPUT_CLASSES = 2`. Make it use sigmoid for the output layer by this condition.

```
if model_output_classes == 2:
    self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=1,
                                   activation="sigmoid")
else:
    self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=model_output_classes,
                                   activation="softmax")
```

It means you will get only one label with a probability range of 0 to 1. You can fix this by edit this variable to a number of your label to use softmax for the output layer instead. Softmax will give you a probability over labels.

Comment: when training the model, it predicts for each label individually. You can see an outer for loop which is `for i in range(len(y_train[0])):` and that's how the model predicts for all the 9 labels by iterating the process 9 times. Therefore it should be two classes inside an iteration

Comment: Inside that loop, It will create a new model for each label individually, and every model was trained to predict each label. I think you save the last one and use it to predict all labels in unseen data in the last code block?

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it but then I got another issue. `text_model.save("model_{}.hd5".format(i))   model=load_model('model_{}.hd5'.format(i))                                                               res = model.predict(np.asarray(item1)) ` This is how I save, load and predict the data.But it gives the error as `ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (2 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=int64)
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}`