# ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel and 'CheckpointLoadStatus' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, save, tf.keras

I am working on categorizing reviews into multiple labels and built a multi-label text classifier by referring to this [code](https://github.com/Moradnejad/Bert-Based-Tag-Recommendation/blob/main/tag-recommendation.ipynb). The classification model is based on the Bert text model. I got an issue regarding how to predict unseen data by the trained model and posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648930/how-to-predict-unseen-data-from-trained-multi-label-text-classification-model). According to the solutions provided there, tried to save my model and load it in the following ways.

```
text_model.save('/tmp/model')
loaded_model=tf.keras.models.load_model('/tmp/model')

result = loaded_model.predict(np.asarray(item))
```

When I try to predict unseen data using the loaded model I get the following error.

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=int64)
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_1')
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs')
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 3:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs')
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 4:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_1')
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

After studying on same cases then I tried using `save_weights` and `load_weights`.code is given below

```
text_model.save_weights("model.hd5") 

loaded_model=TEXT_MODEL(vocabulary_size=VOCAB_LENGTH,
                        embedding_dimensions=EMB_DIM,
                        cnn_filters=CNN_FILTERS,
                        dnn_units=DNN_UNITS,
                        model_output_classes=OUTPUT_CLASSES,
                        dropout_rate=DROPOUT_RATE
                        )
loaded_model=text_model.load_weights('model.hd5')
result = loaded_model.predict(np.asarray(item1))
```

It gives me an error as `'CheckpointLoadStatus' object has no attribute 'predict'`

If this code is not enough I have provided the code for the implementation and training part of the model in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648930/how-to-predict-unseen-data-from-trained-multi-label-text-classification-model) question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. I haven't built the model before loading the weights. Because of that, it didn't initialize layers in the subclassed model and gave the error as `'CheckpointLoadStatus' object has no attribute 'predict'`. The following code shows how I fixed the issue by applying build() method.

```
text_model.save_weights("model.h5")
new_model=TEXT_MODEL(vocabulary_size=VOCAB_LENGTH,
                        embedding_dimensions=EMB_DIM,
                        cnn_filters=CNN_FILTERS,
                        dnn_units=DNN_UNITS,
                        model_output_classes=OUTPUT_CLASSES,
                        dropout_rate=DROPOUT_RATE
                        )
new_model.build((2487,260))
new_model.load_weights('model.h5')
result = new_model.predict([item1])
```